# Support of a measure and Lebesgue decomposition

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $X=[0,1]^n$ endowed with the Euclidean norm and $\mathcal B$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.
Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure and $\mu$ be a finite measure on $(X, \mathcal B)$ with full support (following wikipedia's definition).

Let $\nu_{ac}$ and $\nu_{s}$ be such that $\mu=\nu_{ac}+\nu_{s}$, where $\nu_{ac}$ is absolutely continuous and $\nu_{s}$ and $\lambda$ are mutually singular.

Question 1: Does $\nu_{ac}$ have full support? Is it possible for its support to have Lebesgue measure zero?

Question 2: Are there known results ensuring that $\nu_{ac}$ has full support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $r_n$ is an enumeration of a dense subset of $[0,1]$. Let $$\nu=\sum_n2^{-n}\delta_{r_n}.$$Then $\nu$ has full support and $\nu_{ac}=0$.

Comment: Q1 was a silly/lazy question, apologies about that. Any ideas about Q2?

Comment: @user_newbie10 I can't think of any such condition, other than the obvious $\nu<<m$.